# correct use of pointers

Tags: c, shell, pointers

I'm having trouble implementing shell commands in C.
I guess it's because I'm using pointers wrong, because I'm pretty new to this language. 
Right now, I'm working on "cd" and "export" commands. Change directory works only if I specify the path in the code and not when the user types it. I'm pretty sure it's because of that `args[1]`. I tried to print it, but reports a segmentation fault. Export reports the same and I think it's because a bad management of "args".
What am I doing wrong?

Note: I speak spanish, however I didn't translate some parts of the code as I think they're still understandable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define PROMPT "$"
#define MAX_LINE 512


int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    int n=0;
    char* token;
    char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
    token=strtok(line,delimit);
    while(token!=NULL){
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        args=token;
        n++;
        args++;
        token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    args=token;
    return n;
}

char *read_line(char *line){
    printf("%s%s ",getenv("USER"),PROMPT);
    fflush(stdout);
    line=fgets(line,MAX_LINE,stdin);
    return line;
}


int execute_line(char *line){
    char **args;
    parse_args(args,line);
    check_internal(args);
    return 0;
}

int check_internal(char **args){
    if( strcmp(args, "cd")==0 ){
        internal_cd();
    } else{
        if( strcmp(args, "export")==0 ){
            internal_export();
        }else{
            if( strcmp(args, "source")==0 ){
                internal_source();
            }else{
                if( strcmp(args, "jobs")==0 ){
                    internal_jobs();
                }else{

                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int internal_cd(char **args){
    char buff[50];
    printf("Comando cd \n");
    char directorio []= "/home/jamengual1/Escritorio/FlashDRIVE";
    printf("%s", args+1);
    if (chdir(directorio) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error %d: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
    } else{
        printf("Estás en el directorio: %s \n", getcwd(buff, 50));
        return 1;
    }

}

   //doing it this way(which should be the right one) it reports a Bad Address error
/*int internal_cd(char **args){
    printf("%s","cambio de directorio\n");
    char buff[50];
    printf("Comando cd \n");
    //printf("%s", args[1]); //segmentation fault
    if (chdir(args[1]) == -1)
    {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Error %d: %s\n", errno,strerror(errno));
        perror("Error");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Estás en el directorio: %s \n", getcwd(buff, 50));
    return 1;

}
*/

int internal_export(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el export\n");
    char *variable;
    char *nuevo_valor;
    char *aux;

    variable = strtok(args[1], "=");
    nuevo_valor = strtok(NULL, args[1]);
    aux = getenv(variable);

    if((int)aux == -1)
    {
        perror("Error: getenv");
        return -1;
    }
        printf("VAR: '%s'. Valor: '%s'. Nuevo valor: '%s'\n", variable, aux, nuevo_valor);

    if(!nuevo_valor){
        perror("Error: error de sintaxis");
        return -1;

    }

        if ((setenv(variable,nuevo_valor,1)== -1))
        {

            perror("Error: llamada al sistema con setenv");
            return -1;

        }

        aux = getenv(variable);

        if((int)aux == -1)
        {
             perror("Error: llamada al sistema con getenv");
            return -1;

        }

        printf("Nuevo valor: '%s': '%s'\n", variable, aux);
        return 1;        

}



int internal_source(char **args) {
    printf("%s","éste es el source\n");
    return 1;
}

int internal_jobs(char **args){
    printf("%s","éste es el jobs\n");
    return 1;
}

void main(){
    char line[MAX_LINE]; 
    while(read_line(line)){
        execute_line(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `args[0]` instead of `args[1]`.

Comment: it keeps reporting Bad Address @EliSadoff

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure then. Sorry.

Comment: A few things:  First, your English is flawless, and the Spanish in your code doesn't get in our way.  Your code uses small functions, too, which makes it easy to read.  There are a lot of issues.  Some of them come from not understanding what args is, and how to fill it.  It's possible that the related links on the right of the page will help.  But there's also weird things: `check_internal` calls `internal_cd()`, but internal_cd is defined as `int internal_cd(char **args)`.  It should be `internal_cd(args)`.  Are you sure this even compiles?  Please make sure you only post code that compiles.

Comment: `char **args; parse_args(args,line);` Why are you passing an uninitialized pointer to a function? What should it do with it? This is the first grave problem I caught, there are many more. You should be getting compiler warnings. Don't ignore them, **ever**. Use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (or an equivalent for your compiler), **always**. If you don't understand why you are getting a warning, **ask**. If you are not getting warnings with your code, your compiler is broken, throw it away and download a good free one.

Comment: the code compiles. I'm getting warnings related to pointers, for example in parse_args when I do args=token: assignment from incompatible pointer type (which I understand, because args is a char** and token it's a char*, but this is the only way it divided the line into tokens so I ignored that, not ideal), I'm also passing arguments from incompatible pointer type (when I use strcmp), I'm also getting this warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size at "if((int)aux==-1) and the last one is about implicit declarations of functions(internal_cd, etc.) @n.m.

Comment: I want to say that appearently I can't change the arguments in the functions, because this is an university project with strict rules about that. @ScottMermelstein

Comment: As n.m. said, all of those warnings are highly significant, and many of them are worth questions of their own.  In your case, they all are indicators of something being wrong with your code.  Work on each warning until it goes away.

Comment: I'm going to work on those warnings from now on. @ScottMermelstein One question, how should I initialize char** args? using malloc maybe? Also, ignore the comment to you about the arguments (I misunderstood what you meant in the first comment)

Comment: *the code compiles*. That's only true if you elect to ignore the warnings, which at this point is a rather unwise decision. You **should** treat warnings as errors, and instruct your compiler/IDE to do so. `-Werror` does that.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot wrong with the posted code.  I feel that the OP is actually interested in learning, so I want to answer, but there's a lot of answering to do, so I'm making this a community wiki, hoping others will jump in.

#### Know what a pointer is

The biggest problem is that you're making liberal use of pointers without having a good feeling for them.  For example the line `if((int)aux==-1)` will never evaluate the way you want.  `aux` is a char*, which means it's a pointer to an area of memory assigned to one or more characters.  The value of `aux` is some arbitrary number - it is the address of the memory for the result from `getenv`.  It will never be -1; it's more likely to be something like, for example, 0xdeadf00d - just an arbitary address to a memory location.  However, (in my example), at 0xdeadf00d, you may have the character `'-'` and at 0xdeadf00e, you may have the character `'1'`, and at 0xdeadf00f, you may have the character `'\0'`.  That is, the series of characters in the memory location pointed to by the pointer will contain the string "-1".  (Note that the end of a string is indicated by a byte set to 0, this is how we know it ends.  This concept will get important as we discuss your args variable.)  You can't just cast 0xdeadf00d to an int (it would be 3735941133), and expect it to compare to -1.

To get that line to work correctly, you can do two things: you can compare the string at that location, i.e. by using `if (strcmp(aux, "-1") == 0)`, or you can convert aux to an int, i.e. if `(atoi(aux) == -1)`

Always know what your pointers are pointing to.  Understand that they're pointing to an area of memory that is formatted as a specific data type.

#### So whats a char** ?

A char** is a pointer to an area of memory that will contain one or more char*, and a char* is a pointer to an area of memory that will contain one or more characters.  In this case, `args` is supposed to be a "list of strings".  Creating an args list is actually the hardest part of your project.  You need to deal with allocating the right size of memory, and deal with the fact that you're doing dynamic memory allocation.  Both of those are tough things to a beginner.

Each line you have that says `args=token` is very very wrong.  As you mentioned, it's generating an error of incompatible types.  You want to set a char* to a char*.  Since you can treat pointers as arrays, something like `args[0] = token` would be valid, but that would keep rewriting every token in the same place; you'd only get the last token.  You should want something like `args[n] = token`.  But there's a problem - args doesn't point to anything!  You would need to allocate the space for it!  args itself is supposed to be a memory location pointing to at least one char*, but it's never set.  It's usually set using `malloc`.

I'm going to recommend a way that avoids dynamic allocation.  There's so much to learn right now without dealing with allocation and the subsequent risk of memory leaks; this will at least let you focus on pointers.

```
#define PROMPT "$"
#define MAX_LINE 512
#define MAX_ARGC 128
char **args[MAX_ARGC] /* this defines args as a global char**, holding up to MAX_ARGC values */

int parse_args(char **args, char *line){
    /* char **args is no longer necessary, since I made it global, but you can leave it */
    int n=0;
    char* token;
    char delimit[]=" \t\r\n\v\f";
    token=strtok(line,delimit);
    while(token!=NULL){
        if (n>MAX_ARGC) {
            perror("Too many arguments")
        }
        printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
        args[n]=token;
        n++;
        token=strtok(NULL,delimit);
    }
    printf("token%i: %s\n",n,token);
    args[n] = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

I call it MAX_ARGC because there's a convention in c where we keep track of the number of arguments in an arg list with a variable of that name.  The name doesn't really matter, though.

Note that I add a 0 at the end.  Just like you terminate a "string" by putting a `'\0'` character, you can terminate a list of pointers with a null pointer.  When you loop through the list, you finish your loop when it equals NULL.  (This avoids the argc thing.)

The dynamic way to do it is to find out how many arguments you have, allocate space for that many pointers with + 1 for a NULL pointer at the end, and then put each pointer into the allocated space.  If that's required, you'll have to do it; what I provided can be a good stepping stone so you can get your pointers under control first.

#### Other things

You may have an issue with using the return value `line` from fgets.  I believe most compilers let you get away with it, but it's officially undefined behavior.  I'll leave that for another day.

Make sure you pass args into internal_cd.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, now I understand much better what I'm working with. I have some questions: I've changed the function check_internal using args[0] to compare now and passing args to the function that I'm calling and it works now dividing into tokens and all that, it even gets the right directory (I know that because I print args[1] and it's the same path I introduced before), however it doesn't change it, it just says there's no such file or directory, maybe it's because of that '\0' you mention, but I can't see where you added it.

Comment: If you're calling `chdir`, and it says `no such file or directory`, then that's the problem - the directory isn't found.  Maybe you're looking for a relative directory from the wrong directory?  Try using `cd` on your command line, with the same path, and see if you get the same result.  Test with explicit paths (like `/home`) and with relative paths from the directory in which you're executing.

Comment: I'm at /Desktop and if for example I write "cd /home" I still get no such file or directory. Also I get a warning saying that parse_args argument 1 (which is args) is a char***, and I see that args is initialized as char**, I don't understand this. Again, when you say "Note that I add a 0 at the end" what do you mean? Where is it? Thanks@ScottMermelstein

Comment: Oh, about the '\0'.  Strings in c are null terminated.  In a string's location in memory, it will have all the characters you expect (in my example in the answer, that's '-', '1', followed by a '\0' character, to show the end of the string.  You need something like this to show when the string is done.  If you read the documentation on strtok, you'll see that it replaces the separator you're looking for with a '\0' each time it finds a separator character.  That way, when you use the return value of strtok, you're just getting the string you need.